# Need to decode &nbsp; to space in html and other special character also

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, special-characters, decode

How I can decode html which should removed or replaced with appropriate characters like  the `&nbsp;` should be replace with " "  (space).

How about other special characters.

Comment: thing is to decode the string not to escape.

Comment: "decode" = "unescape". Have a look at the answers, there are (as far as I can see it) various solutions to decode HTML entities, including links to complete code.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a method yourself like below:

```
+ (NSString *) replaceHTMLEntitiesInString:(NSString *) htmlString {
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@" "];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;" withString:@"\""];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">"];
    return htmlString;
}
```

Comment: no I dont want to manually removing all the specail characters.I want something which does in one line of code.

Comment: I will be glad to know any other good way as I am doing this thing manually. :-)

Comment: This is what you looking for https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser